# pgf: 3D Graphing sqrt(-x-y^2+8) results in a jagged surface

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

The plot of this specific elliptic paraboloid, sqrt(-x-y^2+8) comes out looking like this. I've tried parameterizing the surface, writing the equation in different forms, and messed around with the domain. The error I get most of the time is something about the z axis and having a mismatched number of rows and cols. Can someone help me by figuring out to make the surface smooth and well just not look like this?
[image]

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{3d, calc}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=center]
        \addplot3[domain=-3:3, y domain=-3:3, samples=10, surf, shader=interp] {sqrt(-x-y^2+8)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please can you add a class so this can be compiled?

Answer (score 2):

### The issues

Because PGFPlots samples points within the domain [−3,3] × [−3,3] then constructs a plot from evaluating *z*-coordinates, there are two unfortunate problems we encounter when trying to plot this particular surface. First, the equation *z* = sqrt(−*x* − y<sup>2</sup> + 8) is complex on a subset of the domain, but PGFPlots cannot plot complex values. We can use `unbounded coords=jump` to resolve this first problem—this tells PGFPlots to make jumps where coordinates are `nan`.

The second problem is a more of a hindrance to handle. PGFPlots does not sample evenly along the lower bound of the surface, which occurs where *z* = 0. This will result in a series of jagged-looking spikes along the bottom of the graph when PGFPlots attempts to stitch the evaluated points into a complete graph. A workaround for this problem is to use an if-statement that sets sufficiently small values (less than 0.2) to zero, which removes some of the roughness from the bottom of the graph.

### Result

[image: A paraboloid that opens up along the negative x-axis is showed on a graph for positive values of z. This essentially shows half of the paraboloid.]

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{3d, calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xmin = -4,
    xmax =  4,
    ymin = -4,
    ymax =  4,
    axis equal image,
    unbounded coords = jump
  ]
    \addplot3[
      domain  = -3:3,
      samples = 80,
      shader  = interp,
      surf,
    ] {-x-y^2+8 < 0.2 ? 0 : sqrt(-x-y^2+8)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

To be honest, I’m not sure whether there’s a way to change PGFPlots’ sampling intervals for the second problem, but I’d be happy for feedback in the comments if this can be improved.

Comment: Hey, just want to thank you @gz839918 for answering my question. Obviously, adding the < 0.2 ? 0 argument will make some parts outside the "real" (complex) domain of the function show a flat surface rather than being empty.  Is there any way to eliminate that or is it not possible?

Comment: @tangula I'm glad it helped! I'm not sure about the answer to your question, but it may be possible to perform a custom sample of points, by using a for-loop to sample points on *z* = 0 then passing all evaluated points with `\addplot3 coordinates`. I wouldn't know for sure until somebody tries it, though...

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%axis lines=center,
]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=faceted interp, line join=round,
%z buffer=sort,
domain=-3:3, y domain=-3:3,
samples=30,
unbounded coords=jump,
] {sqrt(-x-y^2+8)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Surface plot]